# Node.js express app architecture with testing

Tags: node.js, express, testing, architecture

Creating new project with auto-testing feature.
It uses basic express.

The question is how to orginize the code in order to be able to test it properly. (with mocha)

Almost every controller needs to have access to the database in order to fetch some data to proceed. But while testing - reaching the actual database is unwanted.

There are two ways as I see:

1. Stubbing a function, which intends to read/write from/to database.
2. Building two separate controller builders, one of each will be used to reach it from the endpoints, another one from tests.

just like that:

```
let myController = new TargetController(AuthService, DatabaseService...);
myController.targetMethod()

let myTestController = new TargetController(FakeAuthService, FakeDatabaseService...);
myTestController.targetMethod() // This method will use fake services which doesnt have any remote connection functionality
```

Every property passed will be set to a private variable inside the constructor of the controller. And by aiming to this private variable we could not care about what type of call it is. Test or Production one.

Is that a good approach of should it be remade?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, It's considered to be a good practice as it is actually a dependency injection pattern